# Install Glibc2 using Yum

Tags: linux, yum, openoffice, glibc, glib

I'm trying to install glibc2 version 2.11 that's needed for openoffice 3.4
https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=119393

but i can't seem to find the dependency with yum. 
I already have the following dependencies installed.

```
glibc.i686                                2.5-49.el5_5.7               installed
glibc.x86_64                              2.5-49.el5_5.7               installed
glibc-common.x86_64                       2.5-49.el5_5.7               installed
glibc-devel.x86_64                        2.5-49.el5_5.7               installed
glibc-headers.x86_64                      2.5-49.el5_5.7               installed
libc-client.x86_64                        2004g-2.2.1                  installed

and

glibc.i686                                2.5-81.el5_8.2               updates
glibc.x86_64                              2.5-81.el5_8.2               updates
glibc-common.x86_64                       2.5-81.el5_8.2               updates
glibc-devel.i386                          2.5-81.el5_8.2               updates
glibc-devel.x86_64                        2.5-81.el5_8.2               updates
glibc-headers.x86_64                      2.5-81.el5_8.2               updates
glibc-utils.x86_64                        2.5-81.el5_8.2               updates
```

I ran the following to get the version but it shows something different

```
[root@***** /]# ./lib64/libc.so.6
GNU C Library stable release version 2.5, by Roland McGrath et al.
```

Can someone please help?

Thanks!

EDIT : I'm using CentOS 2.6.18-128.1.10.el5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone please help?

Actually, no. glibc is a core part of the distro and cannot be upgraded casually. Rebuild OO from source.

Comment: do you mean that the CentOS version i'm using cannot have the glibc2 dependency or that it will be dangerous to do so?

Comment: If you're looking for large upgrades such as this one, CentOS is not the distro for you due to its basis of "stability".

Comment: oh i see. so i guess i'll just downgrade to OO 3.1 then. that sounds like a safer and quicker option than upgrading the whole OS! thanks!